# Can we record components in qf-test if application is launched inside docker container?

Tags: qf-test

When we launch application without docker container, we are able to record the components. But, when we launch inside docker container, record button is disabled.

When we launch standalone application inside docker container we are not able to record the component.

Comment: Is QF-Test also running inside this docker container? And is your application connected to QF-Test?